# composer won't update 8.6.13

Tags: updating, composer

I can't update Drupal 8 from 8.6.10 to 8.6.13 -- please help!

composer.json -- partial

```
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.0.24",
        "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^1.4",
        "drupal/core": "^8.6.0",
        "drupal/bootstrap": "^3.11",
        "drupal/views_accordion": "^1.1",
        "drupal/token": "^1.1",
        "drupal/pdf": "1.x-dev",
        "drupal/pathauto": "^1.1",
        "drupal/contact_block": "^1.4",
        "drupal/blocktabs": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/smtp": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/viewerjs": "1.x-dev",
        "drupal/group": "^1.0@RC",
        "drupal/field_permissions": "^1.0@RC",
        "drupal/libraries": "^3.0@alpha",
        "drupal/admin_toolbar_tools": "^1.23",
        "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^1.23",
        "drupal/alertbox": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/ctools": "^3.0",
        "drupal/login_emailusername": "^1.1",
        "drupal/anchor_link": "^1.6",
        "drupal/download_count": "1.x-dev",
        "drupal/views_data_export": "^1.0@alpha",
        "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.6",
        "drupal/google_analytics": "^2.3"
    },
```

composer outdated "drupal/*"

```
drupal/admin_toolbar       1.23.0       1.26.0      Admin Toolbar improve the default Drupal Toolbar, it lets the hover of sub menus.
drupal/admin_toolbar_tools 1.23.0       1.26.0      Adds menu links to the Admin Toolbar.
drupal/blocktabs           1.0.0-alpha6 1.0.0-beta3 Block Tabs.
drupal/bootstrap           3.11.0       3.17.0      Built to use Bootstrap, a sleek, intuitive, and powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development.
drupal/coder               8.2.12       8.3.1       Coder is a library to review Drupal code.
drupal/core                8.6.10       8.6.13      Drupal is an open source content management platform powering millions of websites and applications.
drupal/csv_serialization   1.3.0        1.4.0       Provides CSV as a serialization format.
drupal/ctools              3.0.0        3.2.0       Provides a number of utility and helper APIs for Drupal developers and site builders.
drupal/field_permissions   1.0.0-rc1    1.0.0-rc2   The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.
drupal/google_analytics    2.3.0        3.0.0       Allows your site to be tracked by Google Analytics by adding a Javascript tracking code to every page.
drupal/pathauto            1.2.0        1.3.0       Provides a mechanism for modules to automatically generate aliases for the content they manage.
drupal/smtp                1.0.0-beta3  1.0.0-beta4 Allow for site emails to be sent through an SMTP server of your choice.
drupal/token               1.1.0        1.5.0       Provides a user interface for the Token API and some missing core tokens.
drupal/views_accordion     1.1.0        1.2.0       Provides an accordion views display plugin.
```

composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies

```
Dependency "asm89/stack-cors" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "composer/semver" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "doctrine/annotations" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "doctrine/common" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "easyrdf/easyrdf" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "egulias/email-validator" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "guzzlehttp/guzzle" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "masterminds/html5" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "paragonie/random_compat" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "stack/builder" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "symfony-cmf/routing" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "symfony/class-loader" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "symfony/console" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "symfony/dependency-injection" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "symfony/event-dispatcher" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "symfony/http-foundation" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "symfony/http-kernel" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "symfony/polyfill-iconv" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "symfony/process" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "symfony/psr-http-message-bridge" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "symfony/routing" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "symfony/serializer" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "symfony/translation" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "symfony/validator" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "symfony/yaml" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "twig/twig" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "typo3/phar-stream-wrapper" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "zendframework/zend-diactoros" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "zendframework/zend-feed" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
```

Comment: Can you try editing composer.json and adding "webflo/drupal-core-strict": "8.6.13" as a requirement, and then doing `composer update`?  If this works, I'll writeup a better answer about what may be going on.

Comment: White screen of death

Comment: I'm wondering -- is there a way to pinpoint core, instead of doing a full composer update?

Comment: I think I got past the same thing on a similarly pesky site the other day with `composer remove drupal/core; composer require drupal/core:8.6.13 webflo/drupal-core-strict:8.6.13`, or something like that

Comment: what a mess.  ok, trying that

Comment: @Clive that was throwing a zend dependency error.  (for some reason, i was too far ahead for webflo.)  i'm trying this with `composer require drupal/core:8.6.13 webflo/drupal-core-strict:8.6.13 --update-with-all-dependencies` and it seems to be working OK

Comment: I usually remove composer.lock and vendor directories, and then run `composer require drupal/core:8.6.13` in development, and then commit the lock file, and when updating in production "I" run `composer install`.

Comment: @mpdonadio if you'd like, i'd accept the answer

Comment: @Clive -- same, if you want to post an answer with details, please do.

Comment: @mradcliffe that seems reasonable, but is a little "brute force".  However, I do that routinely for other PHP applications, so thank you for the reminder.  FWIW, I'm using Pantheon, and cannot run composer on their system.  I could, however, commit the entire _new_ vendor directory, which is essentially what you end up doing on their system.

Answer (score 2):

```
option 1. composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies
option 2. composer remove drupal/core; composer require drupal/core:8.6.13 webflo/drupal-core-strict:8.6.13
option 3. (if all else fails) remove composer.lock and vendor directories, and then run composer require drupal/core:8.6.13
```

Pulled from comments so other ppl can read answers instead of looking through comments.

Comment: Option 3 worked for me!  1 and 2 failed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Updating drupal core is a little different on pantheon. Usually you would apply the update to core via the pantheon ui as seen [here](https://pantheon.io/docs/core-updates/). See [Drupal Security patches](https://pantheon.io/docs/drupal-security-patches/) for an alternative method.